# Blank path in environment variable causing elevated command prompt to not respond

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, windows-server-2008-r2

While attempting to install composer on my Windows2008r2 server, I navigated to System Properties, Environnment Variables, and Edit Path, but when I changed the path the elevated cmd prompt stopped working. So I deleted the path and left it blank. Now the cmd prompt doesnt work, and the environment variable is still blank.

**Does anyone know the default path for the system variable?**

Comment: Return to a previously created restore point could help.

Comment: Or restoring from backup ...

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem
```

Is all that is required.